# I can not implement same code for textViews array swift4

Tags: arrays, swift, textview

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        let textViews = [answersTextView[0],answersTextView[1], answersTextView[2], answersTextView[3], answersTextView[4], questionTextView]

    for textView in textViews {

        var  range = textView!.selectedTextRange
    var    selectedText = textView!.text(in: range!)
        if range == textViews[0]!.selectedTextRange {
        }

    if range != nil {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: selectedText, message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "KELİME DEFTERİNE EKLE", style: .default) { action in

                self.newWords.append(words(word: selectedText!))
                let propertyList = PropertyListEncoder()
                do { let encoded = try? propertyList.encode(self.newWords)
                    try? encoded?.write(to: wordssarchiveURL)

                }

                print(selectedText!)
                print(self.newWords)

            }
            alert.addAction(action)
            present(alert, animated: true,completion: nil)
        }

    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: i have six textViews in array. but when I choose a word only the first element of the array can be chosen. and the range and selected text is not changed

Comment: when I press a button in the viewContoller performAction is triggered but I just want it to be triggered just a text is selected